# Using rows of expand.grid data frame as inputs to custom function

Tags: r

I've got a custom function that take a vector of 6 variables and return a matrix like so :

```
my_function <- (vect){
a=as.numeric(vect[1])
b=as.numeric(vect[2])
c=as.numeric(vect[3])
d=as.numeric(vect[4])
e=as.numeric(vect[5])
f=as.numeric(vect[6])
.
.(using other custom functions here)
.
return(matrix)
}
```

Now I want to do multiple inputs to my function and get a list of matrices. To create all the inputs I need, I used expand.grid function, for example :

```
> x=expand.grid(29,4:5,1,1,5,95)
> x
  Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6
1   29    4    1    1    5   95
2   29    5    1    1    5   95
```

So now I would like to pass each row of this data.frame as an input to my_function. I tried the do.call function like this but I get an error :

```
> y=do.call(my_function,x)
Error in (function (vect)  : 
   unused arguments (Var1 = c(29, 29), Var2 = 4:5, Var3 = c(1, 1), Var4 = 
c(1, 1), Var5 = c(5, 5), Var6 = c(95, 95))
```

I tried to transpose my data frame x but I get the same error :

```
> y=do.call(my_function,as.data.frame(t(x)))
Error in (function (vect)  : 
  unused arguments (V1 = c(29, 4, 1, 1, 5, 95), V2 = c(29, 5, 1, 1, 5, 95))
```

I'm certainly not using the do.call function properly but I'm running out of ideas... Any help ?

Comment: I think you want `apply(x, 1, my_function)`. The 1 indicates that you're applying by row.

Comment: Thanks Joseph it works ! It was that simple !

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your vector as a list:

```
y=do.call(my_function,list(x))
```

Why: `?do.call`

> do.call constructs and executes a function call from a name or a function and a list of arguments to be passed to it.

If I run this using my defined function, like:

```
do.call(rowmean,x)#of course there's an R function for that
```

Then:

> Error in (function (x)  : 
>     unused arguments (Var1 = c(29, 29), Var2 = 4:5, Var3 = c(1, 1), Var4 = c(1, 1), Var5 = c(5, 5), Var6 = c(95, 95))

using:

```
do.call(rowmean,list(x))
```

Works as expected. The only way to test is if your function is provided.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Well it doesn't work for my function except if there's only 1 row in my data frame x. On the other hand, the solution given by Joseph with `apply(x, 1, my_function)`  works for me. I get a big vector instead of a list of matrices, but at least the calculations are done correctly and I can format it to my pleasing ! And yeah I don't know why I sticked with do.call

Comment: I see, it's hard to know without looking at the entire function.